# Count two tables in MySQL, and display results based on the dates from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the number of records in two tables, and group them together based on the dates from one of the counted tables.

At the moment, I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT efu.id) AS TotalCollections, COUNT(DISTINCT ccs.id) AS TotalCases, efu.completion_date
FROM enviro_figures_upload efu
LEFT JOIN customer_cases_upload ccs ON ccs.customer_site = efu.customer_site
WHERE efu.customer_site = "TGI Friday's Glasgow" 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(efu.completion_date, '%m-%Y') DESC
ORDER BY YEAR(efu.completion_date) ASC, MONTH(efu.completion_date) ASC
```

Which outputs the following results:

```
TotalCollections    TotalCases  completion_date
      52                 8         2014-05-21
      73                 8         2014-06-23
      83                 8         2014-07-02
      89                 8         2014-08-22
      87                 8         2014-09-21
      68                 8         2014-10-06
      85                 8         2014-11-20
      59                 8         2014-12-10
      17                 8         2015-01-05
```

However, the `TotalCases` column isn't being counted properly. There are 8 records altogether in that table, but in the query the number of cases should be counted based on the date (also called `completion_date`). There will be cases that `TotalCases` will return 0, but should be included against the `TotalCollections` and `completion_date`.

So really it should be:

```
TotalCollections    TotalCases  completion_date
      52                 2         2014-05-21
      73                 1         2014-06-23
      83                 1         2014-07-02
      89                 0         2014-08-22
      87                 0         2014-09-21
      68                 1         2014-10-06
      85                 0         2014-11-20
      59                 2         2014-12-10
      17                 1         2015-01-05
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**
Here is some sample data from the `enviro_figures_upload` table:

```
id      completion_date
124114  2014-09-30
124134  2014-10-31
124146  2014-05-23
124148  2014-05-24
124149  2014-05-26
124150  2014-05-27
124151  2014-05-28
124152  2014-05-25
124153  2014-05-29
124193  2014-05-31
124194  2014-05-24
124195  2014-05-26
124196  2014-05-27
124197  2014-05-28
```

Here is some sample data from the `customer_cases_upload`:

```
id      completion_date
2519    2014-10-17
2520    2014-12-15
2521    2014-07-28
2522    2014-12-12
2523    2014-09-27
2524    2014-11-03
2525    2014-05-30
2526    2014-05-22
```

Comment: Please post a small sample for rows from both tables as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TotalCases` is showing 8 because there is no constraint on `customer_cases_upload.completion_date`.

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT efu.id) AS TotalCollections, COUNT(DISTINCT ccs.id) AS TotalCases, efu.completion_date
FROM enviro_figures_upload efu
LEFT JOIN customer_cases_upload ccs ON ccs.customer_site = efu.customer_site 
  and year(efu.completion_date) = year(css.completion_date) 
  and month(efu.completion_date) = month(css.completion_date)
WHERE efu.customer_site = "TGI Friday's Glasgow" 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(efu.completion_date, '%m-%Y')
ORDER BY YEAR(efu.completion_date) ASC, MONTH(efu.completion_date) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the customer_site column is, as the column is not included in your sample data, but I think your LEFT JOIN needs to be more specific. It looks like there are 8 total records in the customer_cases_upload table for the customer_site referenced in your WHERE clause. The LEFT JOIN is joining all 8 records to each row of the enviro_figures_upload table, regardless of the completion_date. Does the customer_cases_upload completion_date match the corresponding enviro_figures_upload completion_date? If so, include this in your LEFT JOIN's ON clause to only join the customer_cases_upload rows to enviro_figures_upload rows with the same completion_date.